# IndexOutOfRange in while loop and route error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using a while loop which gives me an indexoutofrange error. I do not understand why this code would give me this.

This is what I have in my view:

```
@{
    int i = 1;
    while(i < 6)
    {
        <li class="item" id="ti+@i"><img  src="Content/images/items/@Model[i].image_name" /></li>
        i++;
    }
}
```

Also, when I start the website I get a The resource cannot be found error. The website is pointed to start at Home/Index which is this view page.

Controller for that page:

```
DBController controller = new DBController();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<items> items= controller.getItems();
    return View(items);
}
```

I have no clue why this all doesnt work.

Comment: It's because `Model` contains less than five elements.

Comment: @DavidArno five is also not sufficient ;)

Comment: Oops, yes that should have been contains less than **six** elements. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loops in C# usually range from 0 to n-1, so be double-sure that starting at 1 is what you want.

Other than that, the error results probably from the fact that `Model` only contains 5 or less elements, so accessing `Model[5]` results in an error, as the elements in `Model` are indexed from 0 to (at most) 4.

Comment: Thank you! The error seemed to have occured on the bracket {. It was indeed the model that did not contain that amount of elements! Thank you.